# Issue while adding dateslider

Tags: android

I am trying to use the dateslider available at http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/ to my android project. However I am having some issues with it

Here is a layout file called datetimeslider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.SliderContainer
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider"
    android:id="@+id/dateSliderContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.ScrollLayout
        style="@style/Scroller"
        app:labelerClass="com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.labeler.MonthYearLabeler"
        app:labelerFormat="%tb %tY"
        app:childWidth="180dp"/>
    <com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.ScrollLayout
        style="@style/Scroller"
        app:labelerClass="com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.labeler.DayDateLabeler"
        app:labelerFormat="%td %ta"
        app:childWidth="120dp"/>
    <com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.ScrollLayout
        style="@style/Scroller"
        app:labelerClass="com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.labeler.TimeLabeler"
        app:labelerFormat="%tR"
        app:childWidth="80dp"/>
    <include layout="@layout/dialogbuttons"/>
</com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.SliderContainer>
```

However, it doesn't recognized the namespace available at

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider
```

all the attributes 
like

```
app:labelerFormat="%tb %tY"
app:childWidth="180dp"
```

they are not recognized by android. Why is it so?

Comment: How are you including the dateslider code in your project?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work for me as a library, I ended up bringing all the code into my project as if I had coded it myself.  So I'll be watching this one for answer too.

Comment: I am copying the whole code in my project. I changed the package name from com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider to com.mydomain.widgets.DateSlider actually. It somehow doesn't recognize the app:labelerClass,app:labelerFormat. I am not sure how this works actually. So can somebody guide me?

Comment: I'll post details when I get home (several hours from now) if someone else hasn't by then.

Comment: @rajansthapit, would love to hear if you were able to get this to work. It works beautifully in the demo project, and I made that project a library project, but on build I get the same errors related to resource files.

Comment: Yeah it works. I included the code in my project. It took some fine. But finally it worked :)

Comment: Seems I am having the same issue of not being able to include it as a library project.